# How to convert vertical guideline into Percentage

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

This looks easy,After adding Vertical Guideline, When you click on the upper arrow it turns into percentage, but there is something wrong in my android studio, or in the constraint layout version i am using or may be i am doing something terribly wrong  here.

[image]

I have tried everything, but it always shows the same arrorw, and never turns itself to percentage, when  i click on it.

I am using `Android Studio 2.2`, and added this in my gradle.

`compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'`

Kindly guide me how to convert this into percentage.

Comment: Alternatively, try using android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout or PercentFrameLayout views (you can find those in support libraries - com.android.support:percent). Then you can use app:layout_widthPercent="num%" or similar constraints on its children.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works in Android Studio 2.3 with

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
```

However, there are a couple of problems with the usage. Sometimes the icon is hidden under other items, making it difficult to click, and at other times clicking on the icon will select something underneath. I have found you sometimes need to zoom in a great deal and then click right in the middle of the icon on the little triangle. One click will reverse the direction of the guideline and two clicks will convert it to percentage.

If that fails you can always change the xml directly. Replace

```
app:layout_constraintGuide_begin="51dp"
```

with

```
app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.3611111"
```

for example.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Percent Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#percent)

> The Percent package provides APIs to support adding and managing
>   percentage based dimensions in your app.

Add dependency to your Gradle build script, change version depending on your project:

```
compile 'com.android.support:percent:24.2.1'
```

In your Layout, you could add a [PercentRelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html).

> You can specify dimension or a margin of child by using attributes
>   with "Percent" suffix

For instance:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```